# Privacy and security risks of Green Card scanning with or without offical RFID protection envelope

Tags: rfid

The presentation slides by Bishop Fox at [RFID Hacking - Live Free or RFID Hard - 01 Aug 2013 – Black Hat USA 2013 – Las Vegas, NV](https://media.blackhat.com/us-13/US-13-Brown-RFID-Hacking-Live-Free-or-RFID-Hard-Slides.pdf) briefly describes a number of RFID hacking approaches, and ends with a picture and statement about the sleeves that are now distributed with United States Permanent Resident Cards ("Green Cards"):

```
USA - Green Card Sleeve
• Since May 11, 2010, new Green Cards contain an RFID chip
• Tested Carl’s “protective sleeve”, doesn’t block anything.
• False sense of security
```

But details are hard to come by.

Questions:

- Does the official sleeve provide any protection? Has it been quantified?
- What alternative protective shielding alternatives might work better?
- Which RFID technology, protocol, etc is used by Green Cards?
- What are the privacy and security risks of using Green Cards with or without the official sleeve, or others that might be recommended?

Comment: Before talking about the sleeves it would be nice to know what info the green cards broadcast over NFC and what authentication is required, if any.

Comment: @AndréBorie Yes, good point. I meant for that to be part of the question. I tried to clarify it.

Comment: About which RFID (more specifically, NFC) protocol is used I'm confident it would be ISO14443, the same standard used for credit cards and passports.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, it appears that Green Cards and passports from many countries use the [ISO/IEC 14443](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_14443) NFC protocol in some form. Wikipedia documents a number of common but optional protection mechanisms for [Biometric passports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biometric_passport), but notes attacks on them, e.g. allowing attackers to clone a passport by examining and scanning the unopened postal mail package in which it is delivered.  See [Radio-frequency identification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification#Passports_2)